# How to put a view with LoadMore Button in UITableView after the cell

Tags: swift, button, view, tableview

I am building a project. Firstly, I have a TableView, and I'll put a LoadMore Button in a View at the end of the Cell. Like this:

[image: The Style I want]

But one of my TableView doesn't show the View with the LoadMore Button. I can't find what's wrong.

[image: Fail with no LoadMore Button]

If I put the view before the cell,then it is showing correctly. But if placed after the cell it doesn't show. Please kindly suggest solution.

Comment: the View Hierarchy with the LoadMore Button
http://i.imgur.com/1G73Zsn.jpg
the View Hierarchy with no LoadMore Button
http://i.imgur.com/eo483Vw.jpg

Comment: Why don't you just put the `loadMore` button in the last cell of your displayed cell array?

Comment: Can you show your constraints?

Comment: To  Julian Lee :
this one can show the View with button
http://i.imgur.com/j0A9c2g.png,
this one can not show the View
http://i.imgur.com/P0cXHpe.png

Comment: To  ZGski:
I'm just a beginner learning Swift.
Maybe my method can't word,then I'll learn how to put the loadMore button in the last cell in my displayed dynimic cell array.Thanks!

Comment: I want to figure out why one is working fine,But the other can not.

Comment: If I move the View before the Cell,likes this : http://i.imgur.com/F7KSJUQ.png.  It can shows:http://i.imgur.com/aX4ytSk.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many rows are you telling the tableview to have?

How are you controlling which version of the prototype cell is displaying?

```
numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return dataSources.count + 1
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, CellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexpath.row > dataSources.count {
         return LoadMoreCell()
    }
    return NormalCell()
}
```

the method signature might be a little different there but the concept is the same

Comment: I use dynamic Cell to get JSON data,there is my function : 

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataSources.count
    }

there return 1

Comment: I just return the NormalCell only. Because I didn't use Cell to put the Button. I used a View in the TableView after the Cell .Maybe I can try your method.Thanks!

Comment: first, number of sections is not the number of cells, but instead the number of sections of cells. Second, if you want a special cell at the end of the list, you cannot use only the normal cell, you would have to provide a special call at the end.

Comment: My tableView rows function look like that:  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return JsonData.count
        
    }

Comment: About Second,I want to put a View at the end of the list,but not s special cell.Can I just pull a View into TableView at the storyBoard and let it appear?Sorry I'm a beginner and don't know if answer your question.Thanks!

Comment: A UITableView is a collection of UITableViewCells stacked dynamically in a list , a UITableViewCell is just a UIView that can be used by a UITableView.  So, you could have your customer UIView inherit from UITableViewCell or you could put your UIView outside of the UITableView.

Comment: I found that I wrote this Code:
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
It make my view disappear.Thanks!