# How to add a "Load More" cell that when pressed adds more rows to the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableview only initially shows 5 cells plus a "load more" cell when is pressed more cells will be presented.  I'm downloading JSON data and splitting it into 3 arrays, one for the total data, one for data for only the first 5 cells and one for the remaining data after the first 5 cells' data is subtracted from the total data.

I saw this question on here: [Load More Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330990/how-to-put-a-view-with-loadmore-button-in-uitableview-after-the-cell) and tried implementing what they did but with little success.  This is what we have so far -

[image: Storyboard]

pretty simple, straightforward storyboard with 2 different cells, the first one is the "test cell" which contains the JSON data, the second one is the "expand cell" that when pressed is supposed to show the rest of the cells. Here is my code so far, I omitted a lot of it to keep this post short, I'm currently getting an error it's marked:

```
  var castArray: [CastData?]? = []
  var first5CastArray: [CastData?]? = []
  var remainderCastArray: [CastData?]? = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let firstArray = first5CastArray {
      return firstArray.count + 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
     }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < (first5CastArray?.count)! {
      let testCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell

      testCell.castImageView.image = first5CastImageArray?[indexPath.row]
      return testCell

    } else {
      let expandCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandCell
      expandCell.moreLabel.text = "More"//Error here -fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
      return expandCell
    }
  }

//Below code never tested because of fatal error from cellForRowAt indexPath!!!!!
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let remainderArray = remainderCastArray {

      for info in remainderArray {
        first5CastArray?.append(info)
      }
    }
expandCell.isHidden = true
       tableview.reload 
      }
```

I'm not completely sure if I'm going about this the right way, any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you sure that your moreLabel outlet is correctly linked from your storyBoard to your expandCell class?

Comment: Yes it is, I just checked

Comment: Check the identifier of your cell @SwiftyJD

Comment: The cell identifier is correct, still getting the nil

Comment: use if let in the cell initialization from UITableView, to see if is problem with the tableView dequeue or the problem is related to UILabel itself, use `if let expandCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandCell", for: indexPath) as? ExpandCell {}`

Comment: Still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Go back to your storyboard, select that cell again, go to "Attributes Inspector" tab, type in `expandCell` in `identifier` field.